# How can load data into Abstract Model in python?

Tags: python, optimization

How can load data into Abstract Model in python?
I mean... I tried to do it using for loops. However, there are some problems. Which way is easy to use? Because my model is complex...

Comment: I think you should provide more information. What is "data", what do you mean by Abstract Model. Add some code to show what you tried to do. If your model is complex, maybe try with simple one, make it work, then build upon it.